# To copy Linux directory structures/tree **only** without files and preserve attributes

Tags: bash, directory, attributes, copy

How to copy Linux directory structures/tree **only** and preserve their attribute

e.g. foo and tmp are directories in a current working dir., this below not work

```
cp --preserve=all foo tmp
```

Nor the **whole** dir. copy :

```
cp --preserve=all -r foo tmp
```

This will copy both directories and files.

How is the true method the most efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a first approach, using linux `rsync`, with this:

```
rsync -a --exclude "*.*" foo/ tmp/
```

We exdlude `*.*`, that is to exclude files with file.extension syntax. If you have dir.dir directory, it will not be copied. In the contrary, a file README will be copied.

---

A second solution is more complex, using `find, sed, mkdir, ...` like this:

```
find foo -type d -exec bash -c "d=\"{}\"; dnew=\$(echo \$d | sed 's/^foo/tmp/') ; mkdir -p \$dnew ; chmod --reference=\$d \$dnew ; chown --reference=\$d \$dnew ; touch --reference=\$d \$dnew " \;
```

This strictly copies only directories, ignoring all files. Preserving attricuttes such as mode, owner, creation and modification dates, but some extended directory attributes might not be preserved.

Here

> $d: old directory
>
> $dnew: new directory

Attributes copied:

> ```
> > chmod --reference=olddir newdir # we copy modes rwx,
> > chown --reference=olddir newdir # we copy owner,
> > touch --reference=olddir newdir # we copy dates.
> ```